# displaying input in Angular2 based on user selection in <select>

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a  element within a  which contains 2 items in it - New, Used

This is followed by 2  elements in a separate  which should be hidden depending on whether New or Used is selected.

Please see my code below and advise where I am going wrong?

div containing mileage should be shown when user selects 'New'but is also shown when selecting 'Used'- see attachment.

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="SelectedCarType" 
name="SelectedCarType" id="SelectedCarType">
<option *ngFor="let c of CarTypes" [value]="c.CarTypeId">
   {{c.CarDescription}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType ===1" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
   <label class="label label-info" for="Mileage">Mileage:</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Mileage" id="Mileage"/>
 </div>

<div class="form-group" style="width:50%">
    <label class="label label-info" for="Kilometres">Kilometres:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Kilometres" 
 id="Kilometres" />
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your second element doesn't have an `*ngIf`

Comment: I want the first element to be hidden - the 2nd one should be displayed at all times...when the page loads the 'New' is selected - which has a value of 1... the mileage <div> should not be displayed...

Comment: Set ngModel as a Two way data-binding [(ngModel)]

Comment: @Vignesh Thanks that did the trick

Comment: ok i will elaborate the answer so mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Two-Way Data-Binding like this [(ngModel)]

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="SelectedCarType" >
<option *ngFor="let c of CarTypes" [value]="c.CarTypeId">
   {{c.CarDescription}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType === 1" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
   <label class="label label-info" for="Mileage">Mileage:</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Mileage" id="Mileage"/>
 </div>

<div class="form-group" style="width:50%">
    <label class="label label-info" for="Kilometres">Kilometres:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Kilometres" 
 id="Kilometres" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="SelectedCarType" 
name="SelectedCarType" id="SelectedCarType">
<option *ngFor="let c of CarTypes" [value]="c.CarTypeId">
   {{c.CarDescription}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType ===1" class="form-group" style="width:50%">
   <label class="label label-info" for="Mileage">Mileage:</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Mileage" id="Mileage"/>
 </div>

<div *ngIf="SelectedCarType != 1"  class="form-group" style="width:50%">
    <label class="label label-info" for="Kilometres">Kilometres:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Kilometres" 
 id="Kilometres" />
</div>
```